# Как заблокировать обновление RAND в ячейках и разрешать по кнопке?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Проблема в том, что содержимое листа обновляется при любой правке. А мне надо чтобы он один раз сгенерировался и с ним можно было работать. Можно как-то отключить/включить работу формулы RAND в документе? Или заменить формулы на работу скрипта...

Пример: Таблица

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | =RAND() |  |
| 2 | =RAND() |  |

Она генерирует числа при загрузке

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.33333 |  |
| 2 | 0.55555 |  |

Я работаю с данными

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.33333 | Число меньше 0.5 |
| 2 | 0.55555 |  |

Но когда я вписываю B1, то всё пересчитывается и уже не соответствует действительности

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.66666 | Число меньше 0.5 |
| 2 | 0.44444 |  |

Поэтому нужно найти способ остановить пересчёт.

Answer (score 0):

Данные как вносятся? В одном из проектов данные заносятся через форму и триггером добавляется значение в эту же строку.

А так можно и руками копипастить рандомное значение в нужную ячейку. После этого оно изменяться не будет. Можно сделать скрипт, который будет заполнять ячейку рандомным значениям. Как запускать скрипт уже на ваш выбор, либо триггером на изменение, либо по времени, либо по кнопке на листе, либо из пункта главного меню.

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc */

function freezeValue() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveRange();
  range.copyTo(range, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("⚙️ Advanced")
    .addItem("Freeze Value", "freezeValue")
    .addToUi();
}
```

Есть еще вариант через лямбду. Оно не обновляется. Но надо потестить.

```
=LAMBDA(x; x)(RAND())
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Comment: aleksandr barakin, понял. Постараюсь не повторить ошибки. Дополнил ответ, чтоб он был похож на ответ :)

Comment: В целом, я действительно реализовал через скрипт (да, действительно дёргаю из дополнительного пункта в UI), но не доволен таким решением =)